# Failing to upload file to Azure Fileshare

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-files, powershell-az-module

I am trying to upload a csv file to azure file share. Below is the cmdlets I am using:

```
$folderPath="/"
$ctx=(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'rg-aexch' -Name 'storaexch').Context  
$fileShare = Get-AZStorageShare -Context $ctx -Name "fs-aexch"
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source "E:\ Exc\dash\batch1.csv" -Path $folderPath -Force
```

But I am getting the below error:

> Set-AzStorageFileContent : Cannot bind parameter 'Share'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageFileShare" value of type
> "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageFileShare" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare".
> At line:13 char:37

- ```
  Set-AzStorageFileContent –Share $s –Source $localFile
  ```
- ```
                                  ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzStorageFileContent], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageFileContent

Comment: got it working :
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Sharename $fileShare.Name -context $ctx -Source "E:\ Exc\dash\batch1.csv" -Path $folderPath -Force